# PythonGTK - Can't write special characters into database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, pygtk

I wrote the following program that writes into a sqlite3 table:

https://www.adrive.com/public/sJZKt3/program.py

It works fine except when trying to save language specific characters, for example:

Ää,ß, ç

When trying to insert into the table I get following error message:

> SQL Error
>
> You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that
> can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is
> highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to
> Unicode strings.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can I automatically change the strings to unicode strings? I thought adding # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
would do the trick...

Comment: In python2 you have to decode the string. See the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) for information. Otherwise, you can switch to python3 which uses unicode strings by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change text to unicode so you can insert

```
text = "äöü"
text = text.decode("utf8")
```

Comment: Is this in python3? Because in python2 i'm getting this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte